# VPN server without port forwarding

Tags: networking, vpn, nat, port-forwarding, remote-access

I started at a small company at the beginning of this year and saw they were using dropbox for everything -- I was a bit shocked and told them to buy a Synology NAS and keep 1 Dropbox account for backup and file sharing with clients (Saves them a fortune).

An important part of this solution is they needed remote access to the files (Easy -- Synology has a  built in VPN server) The problem is now that our business shares the internet connection with another business and they seem to have broken their Draytek Router, I cannot access the management console (HTTP, SSH, Telnet) -- Draytek themselves couldn't help me and suggested to do a factory reset (other company does not want me to do that as they cannot remember what settings they need to make everything keep working...).

As UPnP didn't work I had no way of opening ports, I managed to use SSH to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance and bind the port so the VPN connection tunnels through the SSH connection. unfortunately this is slow and shows a high usage on the Synology CPU (But it works).

My real question is, is there a better way?

- I have been looking at ipv6 tunneling but couldn't successfully set it up as ICMP is blocked by the router (apparently necessary? -- not sure if it would work anyway)
- UPD hole punching, is this reliable enough to spend the effort of setting something up?

Comment: Really? Reset the Draytek router and let the other business suffer the consequences of their mistake. Or better yet, stop sharing Internet access with them.

Comment: Unfortunately the other business are also our landlords, I have been told to tip-toe round them and cause minimum upset, many hours of my time would have been saved otherwise. As for a separate internet connection - I will try and persuade them but unfortunately I am just "the guy who promised but couldn't deliver" at the moment so my suggestions carry little weight :(

Comment: Yoiu should also reject in the most forceful terms any attempt to blame you for the failings of this other business.

Comment: I am definitely, but unfortunately there is no one in either company who can really understand what my problem is (They're Non-technical), so ultimately it falls on me. the 3rd party IT support company has been less than helpful: "That router was there when we took over - its nothing to do with us" has been the official response from any current or previous support company.

Comment: It's pretty obvious at this point that any solution is going to be non-technical and is going to require your management to step on some toes and cause some upset, because that's above your pay grade. There's nothing more you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If standalone router, put in a switch, on the WAN side, and add your own router. Let them have the Draytek thing alone and take control.